# How do I resolve a backup restoration error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb, mysqlimport, file-import

I am trying to reconstruct a website from backups. When I try to import the database content via PHPMyAdmin, I get the following error:

*Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mb_strcut() expects parameter 1 to be string, bool given in /home/customer/public_html/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/File.php:772 Stack trace: #0 /home/customer/public_html/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/File.php(772): mb_strcut(false, 0, 32768) #1 /home/customer/public_html/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Import.php(432): PhpMyAdmin\File->read(32768) #2 /home/customer/public_html/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Plugins/Import/ImportSql.php(135): PhpMyAdmin\Import->getNextChunk(Object(PhpMyAdmin\File)) #3 /home/customer/public_html/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Controllers/ImportController.php(635): PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\Import\ImportSql->doImport(Object(PhpMyAdmin\File), Array) #4 /home/customer/public_html/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Routing.php(186): PhpMyAdmin\Controllers\ImportController->index(Array) #5 /home/customer/public_html/phpmyadmin/index.php(18): PhpMyAdmin\Routing::callControllerForRoute('/import', Object(FastRoute\Dispatcher\GroupCountBased), Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjecti in /home/customer/public_html/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/File.php on line 772*

I have looked everywhere to try and find how to overcome the problem, but so far, no joy.

Any help more than welcome.

We have tried importing on to two different hosting platforms (Plesk and Siteground's own).

Plesk produced an "unknown" Plesk version error.

Also tried importing a dump and importing directly via PHPMyAdmin. Dump did not recognise the file, PHPMyAdmin produced this error. We also tried to restore the back up without any luck. Finally, we tried to open the mySQL zip file directly but it is password protected.

Note we have no control of the file source, which is the only back up.
Note 2. I get the same import error when I try to import to Xampp local server

Comment: where is this backup produced from? afaik phpmyadmin does not password its sql file export. if the backup is from plesk and you have issue restoring it on plesk, it would be best to contact plesk support.

Comment: Thank you, Bagus. I will raise it with them